# Pandas pivot table with repeating values

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a DataFrame similar to this one:

| Name | Name | Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Index |  |  |
| 0 | Apple | 100000 |
| 1 | Apple | 110000 |
| 2 | Tesla | 80000 |
| 3 | Tesla | 85000 |

and I want to make it into the following table:

|  | Year 1 | Year 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 100000 | 110000 |
| Tesla | 80000 | 85000 |

I understand that I need to use a pivot table, but if I use `pandas.pivot` I get this:

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 100000 | 110000 | NaN | NaN |
| Tesla | NaN | NaN | 80000 | 85000 |

And I want to contract it so that there are no NaN cells.

I would be very grateful if you could give me an idea, also maybe not with a difficult code, as I am a beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to add a column to indicate the year.  Assuming every company has a row for all years, and that they appear in order, then you can just use [`pd.GroupBy.cumcount()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html).  Then use that column in the `pivot` call.

```py
In [8]: df = pd.DataFrame({
   ...:     'name': ['Apple', 'Apple', 'Tesla', 'Tesla'],
   ...:     'revenue': [100_000, 110_000, 80_000, 85_000]
   ...: })
   ...:
   ...: print(df)
    name  revenue
0  Apple   100000
1  Apple   110000
2  Tesla    80000
3  Tesla    85000

In [9]: df['year'] = 1 + df.groupby('name').cumcount()
   ...: print(df)
    name  revenue  year
0  Apple   100000     1
1  Apple   110000     2
2  Tesla    80000     1
3  Tesla    85000     2


In [10]: df2 = df.pivot('name', 'year', 'revenue')
    ...: print(df2)
year        1       2
name
Apple  100000  110000
Tesla   80000   85000
```

Comment: Thank you! I did not know how to add the year column, that is what helped me.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an implicit column, year, in order to get it:

```
df['Year'] = df.groupby('Name').cumcount()
```

Then you're ready to continue:

```
df.reset_index(drop=True) # just to clean up your index, may not be necessary
df.pivot(index='Name',columns='Year')
```

Comment: Thanks, I had to choose Stuart's post as the solution as he was the first :)

Comment: That's ok! Thanks!